# Es posible enseñar el texto oculto solo con HTML y CSS?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo proyecto de portfolio, que ire actualizando a medida que aumente mis conocimientos, he estado buscando una manera de hacer que al poner el mouse sobre el nombre(el elemento a con el id "adrian", se muestre más información (es decir, se muestre el div con el id "more-information"), es posible hacer eso (o algo parecido a esto) solo utilizando HTML y CSS o necesito a fuerzas saber JavaScript? Porque por ahora solo tengo algo de conocimiento de HTML y CSS este es el código:

```css
.header {
  background: linear-gradient(aquamarine, aqua, deepskyblue);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}

#navbar > .menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: right;

}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.sub-menu {
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 50px;
}

#welcome-section {
      display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

} 

#more-information {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Adrian Polanco</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
    <div class="name"><h2>Adrian Polanco</h2></div>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#welcome-section">About me</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu" >Projects</li>
        <li class="sub-menu" href="#profile-link">My networks</li>
        <li class="sub-menu">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
    <section id="welcome-section">
      <h1>Hi,</h1> <h1>I am <a id="adrian" href="#more-information">Adrian Polanco</a></h1><h1>click on my name to learn more about me :) </h1>
      <div id="more-information">
        <h4>I am a Software Development studying at ITLA as well as self-taught, currently I have special intereset in Front-End Delvelopment</h4>
      </div>
    </section>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es posible hacerlo solo con **`css`**, lo que se me ocurrió hacer fue encerrar dentro de un **`div`** con el id **`#adrian`** a **`#more-information`**, no sería la respuesta exacta ya que el efecto ocurriría cuando pases el mouse encima del div y no del texto **`Adrian Polanco`**, pero traté de acercarme más a tu solución:

```
<section id="welcome-section">
  <div id="adrian">
    <h1>Hi, I am <a href="#more-information">Adrian Polanco</a></h1>
    <div id="more-information">
      <h4>
        I am a Software Development studying at ITLA as well as self-taught,
        currently I have special intereset in Front-End Delvelopment
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>click on my name to learn more about me :)</h1>
</section>
```

Ahora en tu **`css`**, lo que consiste es que cuando pases el mouse por el div **`#adrian`**, el display cambiará a **`block`** al id **`#more-information`**, ya que **`#adrian`** encierra a **`#more-information`**:

```
#adrian {
  text-align: center; /*centramos el texto para dar un mejor resultado*/
}

#more-information {
  display: none; /*el texto permanecerá oculto*/
}

#adrian:hover #more-information {
  display: block; /*al hacer efecto hover en #adrian, afectará a #more-information*/
}
```

Tu código final sería el siguiente:

```css
.header {
  background: linear-gradient(aquamarine, aqua, deepskyblue);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}

#navbar > .menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: right;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.sub-menu {
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 50px;
}

#welcome-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#adrian {
  text-align: center;
}

#more-information {
  display: none;
}

#adrian:hover #more-information {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="name">
    <h2>Adrian Polanco</h2>
  </div>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#welcome-section">About me</a></li>
      <li class="sub-menu">Projects</li>
      <li class="sub-menu" href="#profile-link">My networks</li>
      <li class="sub-menu">Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section id="welcome-section">
  <h1>Hi, I am</h1>
  <div id="adrian">
    <h1>Hi, I am <a href="#more-information">Adrian Polanco</a></h1>
    <div id="more-information">
      <h4>
        I am a Software Development studying at ITLA as well as self-taught,
        currently I have special intereset in Front-End Delvelopment
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>click on my name to learn more about me :)</h1>
</section>
```